# Javascript addEventListener not working in some instances but does work in others

Tags: javascript

Relatively new to Javascript so this might be something completely obvious that I'm overlooking.

I have a very simple HTML page, basically just an empty `<div>` with `id="ind-email-view"`.

I'm trying to create two buttons, one called `reply` and one called `archive`, then use `addEventListener` to run a `function on 'click'` for both buttons.

I'm using the same code for both buttons, but the Reply button I can't get to do anything. What am I missing here?

```js
// Create reply button, append to div, addEventListener
var reply = document.createElement('button');
reply.innerHTML = "Reply";
document.querySelector('#ind-email-view').appendChild(reply);
reply.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('button clicked')
});
  
// Create archive button, append to div, addEventListener
var archive = document.createElement('button');
archive.innerHTML = "Archive";
document.querySelector('#ind-email-view').appendChild(archive)
archive.addEventListener('click', () => {
    archive_email(email);    
});
```

```html
<div id="ind-email-view"></div>
```

`archive_email()` is a function I've created, but it's irrelevant here because the archive button works just fine.

I can't even get the reply button to log a message to the console. Literally nothing happens when I click.

What am I missing here?

EDIT - Sorry, I should have included the entire code, thanks for the suggestion @epascarello. Here is the full javascript that those snippets are from. Hopefully this is enough to pinpoint the issue!

The fetch() functions make an API call. Both of those are working fine as well. (This is for a class-project...the API part has been created by the instructor so there shouldn't be any issues there).

```
function get_email(email_id) {
    // clear out the HTML of the ind-email-view div to get rid of any 
        prior email 
    document.querySelector('#ind-email-view').innerHTML = '';

    // Make API call to get the email details
    fetch(`/emails/${email_id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(email => {

        // Make API call to mark email as read
        fetch(`/emails/${email.id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                read: true
            })
        });

        // Get the email's details from the API call and add them to <div>'s innerHTML
        document.querySelector('#ind-email-view').innerHTML += `<b>From: </b>${email.sender}<br>`;
        document.querySelector('#ind-email-view').innerHTML += `<b>To: </b>${email.recipients}<br>`;
        document.querySelector('#ind-email-view').innerHTML += `<b>Subject: </b>${email.subject}<br>`;
        document.querySelector('#ind-email-view').innerHTML += `<b>Timestamp: </b>${email.timestamp}<br><hr>`;

        // Create reply button
        var reply = document.createElement('button');
        reply.innerHTML = "Reply";
        document.querySelector('#ind-email-view').appendChild(reply);
        reply.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // >>This will get replaced with another function, but I can't even get the console.log() to work on click
            console.log('button clicked')
        });
  
        // display email body
        document.querySelector('#ind-email-view').innerHTML += `<br> <br>${email.body}<br><br>`;

        // Create button to archive emails
        var archive = document.createElement('button');
        archive.innerHTML = "Archive";
        document.querySelector('#ind-email-view').appendChild(archive)
        archive.addEventListener('click', () => {
          archive_email(email);    
        });     
    });
}
```

Comment: Hard to guess from the code provided. The code will run fine, so we need more data to debug it.

Comment: My guess is that you run the code before the document is ready, so it does not find the element.

Comment: @some um, the OP has a reference to the object from the createElement, highly doubt that.

Comment: The code in in your question is missing the archive_email() function. Can you add that to the code in your question?

Comment: Works with a mock archive_email function for me. Maybe there is something else that is wrong. Check if button click works when you click reply first and then archive.

Comment: @epascarello I'm talking about `document.querySelector('#ind-email-view')`, that is executed twice. This will fail if executed before the document where the element is defined is parsed.

Comment: @some that is not going to happen with the single threaded nature of JavaScript and it would throw an error and not continue to the other code that adds the event listener that works. So your assumption is flawed.

Comment: basically `.innerHTML` is the naive way to interact with the DOM. using `createElement`, `appendChild` and `removeChild` will be more useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
document.querySelector('#ind-email-view').innerHTML += `<br> <br>${email.body}<br><br>`;
```

It removes the event listener. innerHTML redraws all the DOM in the element.